# cant find out sum in recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, sum

I'm trying to create a recursive function that displays in order n numbers from greatest to 2 that are pair.

If `n=5` it should display `10 8 6 4 2` and then display the sum of these numbers.
I have used this `$s=$s+$inc` in for loops and it works.

Why doesn't this work in recursive numbers?

```
<?php
$inc = 2;
recv(5);

function recv($v)
{
    global $inc;
    if ($v >= 1) {
        echo $inc * $v . " ";
        $v--;
        $s = $s + $inc * $v;
        recv($v);
    }
}

echo 'The sum is $s';
?>
```

Output is:

> `10 8 6 4 2` The sum is `$s`

Comment: You are literally printing the string `'$s'`.  You need to use double quotes if you want to get `$s`'s value: `echo "The sum is $s";.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `$s` is a local variable, so each time you call `recv()` it's reading from (and writing to) a different copy of it. Similarly, when you finally echo it, it's reading from yet another variable that just happens to have the same name.

What you need to do is return the sum so far from your `recv()` function, and add those up as you go along. Something like this should work better:

```
function recv($v)
{
    global $inc;
    if ($v <= 1) return $inc; // <-- terminal condition
    return ($inc * $v) + recv($v - 1); // <-- recursion
}

$s = recv(5);
echo "The sum is $s";
```

Comment: Just realised I got the terminal condition wrong. It should be `$v <= 1` instead of `$v < 1`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: cant manage to get the 2 function together i mean separatly they work just fine but i have to use the same function recv($v) for ordering the numbers and sum them together any help?

Comment: Do you mean echo the numbers as you go along? Just put `echo ($inc * $v)." ";` after `global $inc;`.

Answer (score -1):

Try `echo 'The sum is '. $s;`

See: [String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score -1):

At first, you should use eigher "" string literals to [varible parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) or [string operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).
At second, you try to echo variable `$s`, wich local for function `recv()`. So, you should make it global (and will not forget about initialization).

Comment: Repeatedly writing to a global variable in a recursive function would have the potential to go badly wrong. A trivial change in the order of operations could give a totally different result.